# dynamically set the carousel width to the window size

Tags: html, css, asp.net, carousel

i am using a bootstrap carousel in asp.net. i want to set the width of the carousel so that it occupies the full width of the browser window with a fixed height if i change the width to 100% it does not work. Following is the code for carousel

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="width:1177px; height:239px; top: 0px; left: 0px;">


<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" style="width:1177px; height:240px; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
<div class="item active">
  <img src='images/image1.jpg' alt="Chains" style="width:1177px"/>
</div>


<div class="item">
  <img src='images/image2.jpg' alt="Chains" style="width:1177px"/>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img src='images/image3.jpg' alt="Chains" style="width:1177px"/>
</div>
  <div class="item">
  <img src='images/image4.jpg' alt="Chains" style="width:1177px"/>
</div>    
</div>
</div>
```

i have set the width of the images and the carousel to the browser window manually but i want this to be dynamic.

following is the CSS

```
.carousel {
position: relative;
}
.carousel-inner {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel-inner > .item {
position: relative;
display: none;
-webkit-transition: .6s ease-in-out left;
      transition: .6s ease-in-out left;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
line-height: 1;
width: 1177px;
}
.carousel-inner > .active,
.carousel-inner > .next,
.carousel-inner > .prev {
display: block;
}
.carousel-inner > .active {
left: 0;
}
.carousel-inner > .next,
.carousel-inner > .prev {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .next {
left: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .prev {
left: -100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .next.left,
.carousel-inner > .prev.right {
left: 0;
}
.carousel-inner > .active.left {
left: -100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .active.right {
left: 100%;
}
```

and also when i scroll to the right the carousel comes on top of sidebar. how do i avoid that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give 100% width to all the width given inline.

I could see some 7-8 width:1177px in html code make all to width:100%

Also in css make width:100% for all the classes.

CODE:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 100%;
      margin: auto;
  }
</style>
<div class="container">
  <br>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="img_chania.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img_chania2.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
      </div>
    
      <div class="item">
        <img src="img_flower.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img_flower2.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can refer for more information http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp